# Folder upload functionality in react/next app

Tags: reactjs, file-io, dropzone, folderbrowserdialog, directory-upload

I'm learning NextJs.
I want to upload folder from client side. is there any way to do it in React/Next JS?

I did try to do it with html input component. `<input  type="file" name="file" webkitdirectory="true"/>` as well as dropzone & jsZip library. but didn't got the solution.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Basically, i want to upload folder from client side. is there any way to do it...?